# Gitlab packages and registry vs Github packages for docker and npm

Tags: docker, github, gitlab

I have a lot of projects hosted on gitlab.

Gitlab's downtime is very high in my region, at least.

So, CI/CD is so confusing with ton of features.

I have hosted all my projectes on a k8s cluster in aws, not using EKS. CI/CD is required.

Gitlab uses shared runner for executing pipelines. So I have to wait a lot of time to pipeline be executed.

I can setup my own runner but that's an extra headeache to setup and mangae.

*Does Github use shared runner also?*

I liked the most about Gitlab is the ability to host docker images and npm packages.

I am planning to move all the projects to github now, due to its high availability.

But, I got to know that Github's package is in beta mode, and it is limited to only `500MB` storage in free tier. *Is it per private repository? OR per organization?*

*Can someone tell me what's size of Gitlab's package and registry in free tier?*

*Will Github's packages  be paid in future?* *They have mentioned there that it is subject to change.*

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. I don't think GitHub uses shared runners. You can have multiple runners simultaneously occurring if delay for CI/CD is a concern.
2. The 500MB is for private repositories. See this [page](https://github.com/features/packages) and scroll down to the section called **Private Repositories**
3. GitHub packages is currently free for public repositories with limitations for private repositories. Can they change their policy? Yes. You are using a free service, after all. Almost any SaaS will change their policies. Docker changed some of their policies recently; [see this](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-hub-image-retention-policy-delayed-and-subscription-updates/#:%7E:text=Two%20months%20ago%2C%20we%20announced,after%20six%20months%20of%20inactivity.). From my experience, GitHub is usually good about notifying of changes in advance, so you should have ample time to move stuff.